# useradd won't work correctly on Debian Squeeze

Tags: debian

system: Debian-60-squeeze-64-LAMP 2.6.32-5-amd64

As root I create a user in an ssh-console:

```
useradd -m -G users myuser
passwd myuser
xxxxxx
xxxxxx
```

su myuser or after login via ssh I get:

```
\[\033[01;31m\]\u\[\033[01;33m\]@\[\033[01;36m\]\h \[\033[01;33m\]\w \[\033[01;35m\]$ \[\033[00m\] plus the cursor
```

Using the tab key the cursor just jumps forward, so no completion here.

Also the arrow keys do NOT work, if I use right arrow key I get:^[[C

What could cause this behavior?

Comment: Try doing: `reset`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

useradd uses /etc/default/useradd to select which shell to give a new user. adduser uses /etc/adduser.conf and is usually what you'd want for interactive users as opposed to system-accounts etc.

At least with my installation useradd selects /bin/sh (which links to /bin/dash) as the shell, while adduser selects bash.

```
chsh /bin/bash myuser
```

will fix the shell for **myuser**, switching to **adduser** instead of **useradd** will avoid future problems of this kind.

Comment: had to use an '-s' in your command, i.e. chsh -s /bin/bash myuser Thanks a lot for your helpful answer!
(added here because I could not find a comment link below your answer, why?)

Comment: Ah, yes. '-s' is indeed the right thing to do. (I could however not comment about the missing comment-link :-) )

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, append '-s /bin/bash' to your useradd command if you really insist on using useradd instead of adduser.

Answer (score 0):

From `useradd` manpage :

> useradd is a low level utility for
>   adding users. On Debian,
>   administrators should usually use
>   adduser(8) instead.

Try to re-create the user, but using `adduser`. I've seen it working much better on different occasions.